# Programmatic way of generating and extracting private address using Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, private-key

I'm not sure why this is so tough but I can't find easy answer to do what I'm trying to do, which is following:

1. Generate a new ETH address using passphrase using Geth (I can do this using "geth account new", and I see public key)
2. It generates a keystore file (which I have after step 1)
3. **All I want to do now is extract public as well as unencrypted private key** (I have the file and the passphrase) **via command line** (either using geth, or openssl or whatever). I can see both after importing it manually using MyEtherWallet but I need to be able to do this for multiple keys so need to do it via command line.

Is there ANY way to do the step 3 without doing it manually using some web interface like MEW?

Thanks in advance.

JT

Answer (score 2):

If you have file and password you can use [keythereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum) library.

```
  const wallet = JSON.parse("<wallet_file>");
  const key = keythereum.recover("<your_password>", wallet);
  console.log(key.privateKey.toString('hex'));
```